# Automatically updating the JFrame components without threading or managing directly

Tags: java, swing, automation, jframe, updating

I have searched around and can't seem to find the solution to an issue I've been having. To start off, I am trying to have some components in my JFrame automatically update when the player health has changed. This means without direct management (i.e with the press of a button). I have tried threading, but have found out while loops are not the best option for the situation at hand. An idea that had occurred was to have some sort of reset of the components inside the JFrame, or the ones related (i.e Health textfield or progress bar) that I could call, without having to set each individual component. I have done some research on it and came across the following

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Any ideas?

If I didn't explain it clear enough here's an example. 
- I have my player's health set to 100
- I click a button, and it sets player health to 75 and calls the reset/refresh of all player health related components
- Player health components are now set to 75.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted is wrong. The updateComponentTreeUI(...) method is used internally by Swing on a LAF change. You are not doing a LAF change. `I click a button` - well then the logic in the ActionListener for that button will simply update the state of all the related components. Depending on the component you use the appropriate "setter" method. For example for a JLabel you would use setText(...).

Comment: I really suggest you bring your project to use custom listeners. Thinking in this you can easly update everything that implements your listeners always you call its "fire" method, however this approach uses some iterations over the interested components (the ones that implements the interface). If you update your question with your atual project structure (classes) you can get better help for making this.

Comment: @LucasSousa Thanks for the feedback, the reason why I don't have any code shown above is because I'm just starting to re-make an older project and wanted to get the structure of how things run down first before diving deep. I just needed some ideas as to how I could do this.

Comment: @andrewlopez No problem. What do you think about the listeners? I think is good option to go. :)

Comment: @LucasSousa I know what event listeners are, but are custom listeners different? If so, could you provide an example, it sounds very interesting. Thanks!